# Python3: Parse xml to get child with specific grandchildren

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I'm looking for a way to write out an xml's child with specific, given values as grandchildren. Is there a way to combine .findall() from Xpath with some kind of logical AND and OR? (or of course some other approach)

Example: I'd like to separate the following xml's **child** book **where** title=Computer Dictionary **AND** (price=24.95 **OR** pages=513)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bookstore>
    <book>
        <title>The Iliad and The Odyssey</title>
        <price>24.95</price>
        <pages>513</pages>
        <comments>
            <userComment rating="4"> Best translation I've read. </userComment>
            <userComment rating="2"> I like other versions better. </userComment>
        </comments>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Anthology of World Literature</title>
        <price>24.95</price>
        <pages>86</pages>
        <comments>
            <userComment rating="3"> Needs more modern literature. </userComment>
            <userComment rating="4"> Excellent overview of world literature. </userComment>
        </comments>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Computer Dictionary</title>
        <price>24.95</price>
        <pages>513</pages>
        <comments>
            <userComment rating="3"> A valuable resource. </userComment>
        </comments>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Cooking on a Budget</title>
        <price>24.95</price>
        <pages>56</pages>
        <comments>
            <userComment rating="4">Delicious!</userComment>
        </comments>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Great Works of Art</title>
        <price>24.95</price>
        <pages>83</pages>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Computer Dictionary</title>
        <price>213.95</price>
        <pages>311</pages>
        <comments>
            <userComment rating="3"> A valuable resource. </userComment>
        </comments>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

Is this even possible with python? Tried already for hours with Xpath and ElementTree. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Should be easy with lxml and xpath (`/bookstore/book[title='Computer Dictionary'][price='24.95' or pages='513']`). What are you expecting for output?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for your proposition! In fact, my expectation is to write out as new xml just the child book, where the discussed values matches. `for book in root.findall("./book[title='Computer Dictionary'][price='24.95']"):` works, but your proposition does the trick not unfortunately.. for example in powershell this would be a oneliner..

Comment: What if more than one book is found? Would you have a separate file for each book or one file with all matching books?

Comment: The real xml, which it is about, is built, that there is just one child, where `title='Computer Dictionary' AND (price='24.95' OR pages='513')` The values came from variables. so this means, there would be just one child namend 'book'. To write out this child (maybe with `tree.write('test.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)` would be the goal.

Comment: Do note that `ElementTree` module has [limited XPath support](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)

Comment: now I understand your proposition. under linux this one works perfect: `xmllint dummy_xml.xml --xpath "/bookstore/book[title='Computer Dictionary'][price='24.95' or pages='513']"`

Comment: So do you still need a Python solution or is xmllint your solution?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, actually I'm still interested in the right solution, even just because there must be a way with python, but I'm gonna drop it for now, to much time invested already.